# Google Apps Scripts - Firebase Getting the Key of the object

Tags: google-apps-script, firebase-realtime-database

I'm practicing on Google apps script using firebase. But having problem on getting the `Key` of each user. What i have is this.

Code:

```
  var database = FirebaseApp.getDatabaseByUrl("https://myfirebase.firebaseio.com/", "mysecretkey");
  var data = database.getData("users")
  Logger.log(data);
```

I've tried `data.key` but it returns `undefined` how can i get the key of each user? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at [the code](https://script.google.com/d/MYeP8ZEEt1ylVDxS7uyg9plDOcoke7-2l/edit?usp=drive_web) for the [Firebase connector](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/firebase/reference), it seems they are simply returning the JSON at the location you call `getData()` on.

This means you can iterate it with regular JavaScript code:

```
for (var key in data) {
  Logger.log(key+"="+data[key]);
}
```

Or a more modern/functional variant:

```
Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key) {
  Logger.log(key+"="+data[key])
});
```